# is it possible to save the web page that is returned by a servlet on the server to access again?

Tags: html, tomcat, servlets

Say I have a servlet that processes form data and returns a web page. Is it possible to store the web page that is returned on the server so that it can be accessed again without filling out the form?

Comment: Take a look at filters.

Comment: I am really new to this. How would a filter allow me to save a new web page on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I think its possible. But mostly it will be possible if the form submitted generated a unique page with unique URL.

Like let say when u submit a form and if it created a URL like

> 'http://example.com/result1.html'

then we can use the Expiration filter to set the Expiration HTTP header and make it cacheable.

But one change is that the caching has to be done by a separate caching server and i hope tomcat cannot do it by itself.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is -

You save the form object along with a unique url generated as key pair value. so key will be your unique url and value will be the form object which you have to display on the page and you got what you want.

Few more hint -

1. To generate unique url suppose your result page is 'http://example.com/result.html' you can add a auto increment number like 'http://example.com/result1.html' managed programatically. or you can also thing about UUID class available in java.